# "missing { inserted" in latex equation mode

Tags: math, latex, equation, beta

I am writing an equation in latex.

```
    \begin{equation}
    \label{eq:beta}
    \beta_{ji}=softmax(w{_b^T}tanh(W_3v{_j^'}+W{_4q^'}))
    \end{equation}
```

But the equation number is not displaying at the **right side**, also the latex giving me an error

```
missing { inserted
```

my equation is displayed here[image]

**what could be the possible reason**

Comment: The `^'` is the problem, try with just `'`. And while it doesn't throw an error, the `{_` is also fishy, which parts do you want to be subscripts. Also have a look at the `\text` macro from amsmath to get correct kerning for whole words and also try `\tanh` to get it correctly in upright font

Comment: Perfect. using ```'``` instead of ```^'``` resolved the issue

Comment: There are way more issues. Please specify which letters should be subscripts.

Answer (score -1):

In LaTeX, you need to specify inside curly brackets separately what string is the subscript and what string is the superscript. Here there are three examples of how this influences the output result:

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:beta}
    \beta_{ji} = softmax( w_{b}^{T} tanh (W_{3} v_{j}^{'} + W_{4q}^{'}) )
\end{equation}


\begin{equation}
\label{eq:beta}
    \beta_{ji} = softmax( {w_{b}}^{T} tanh (W_{3} v_{j^{'}} + W_{4q^{'}}) )
\end{equation}


\begin{equation}
\label{eq:beta}
    \beta_{ji} = softmax( {w^{T}}_{b} tanh (W_{3v_{j^{'}}} + {W^{'}}_{4q}) )
\end{equation}
```